# What is a "jigger of Asperger's"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is a *jigger of Asperger's*? The context paragraph is:

> Page was not a social animal—those who interacted with him often wondered if there were a **jigger of Asperger’s** in the mix—and he could unnerve people by simply not talking. But when he did speak, he often came out with ideas that bordered on the fantastic. As an undergraduate at the University of Michigan, he became obsessed with transportation and drew up plans to replace the school’s mundane bus network with an elaborate monorail system, providing a “futuristic” commute between the dorms and the classrooms.

Source: http://www.wired.com/magazine/2011/03/mf_larrypage/all/1

Comment: The definition of the parts plus the metaphorical meaning for 'jigger' is all there is here. It is not a 'set phrase'. That is, it wouldn't be recognized out of context if you used it in conversation (it only works in this particular situation quoted).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asperger's (a short name for [Asperger syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asperger_syndrome)) is a disorder on the autism spectrum. It is characterized by:

> significant difficulties in social interaction, along with restricted and repetitive patterns of behavior and interests

So, people with Asperger are often thought to be anti-social. A jigger is a small measure, usually used to refer to liquor. In context, your example says:

> Page was not a social animal—those who interacted with him often wondered if there were a jigger of Asperger’s in the mix

The term "jigger of Aspberger's" is saying that since Page is not social, some people think that he has at least some small measure of the disorder. Further, as @Colin points out, "a jigger... in the mix" continues the metaphor of creating or mixing a cocktail.

Comment: Note that "a jigger ... in the mix" is continuing the metaphor of mixing a cocktail.

Answer (score 3):

A [jigger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jigger_%28bartending%29) is a device for measuring a shot of an alcoholic drink originally a measure of 1.5 fluid ounces. Here is a picture from Wikipedia

[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2a/Jigger.jpg]

So a "jigger of ..." is metaphorically a small amount.

Comment: so BIG ! :0        ????

Answer (score 1):

"Asperger" here refers to [Asperger's Syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asperger_syndrome) People who have this have difficulty interacting socially. The reason Asperger's syndrome was referred to was because the article you linked to was talking about Page, who "was not a social animal".

"Jigger" here has a meaning of a little of something.

Thus, when the article states: "those who interacted with him often wondered if there were a jigger of Asperger’s," it's saying that people wonder if Page has a little of Asperger's syndrome.